# Image Texture not showing up

Tags: modeling, texturing, error

The object is UV unwrapped, I set the material's base color as Image Texture, you can see the nodes. It does not appear on the model either in Viewport Shading and Rendered. I cannot figure out a way to make it appear. Here is the node setup and material settings.[image]

Comment: Forgot to mention, the image exists and it is fully functional, it even shows up in the UV editor.

Comment: Have you checked if several materials on this object? (we can't see it, the list is restricted to the selected one)

Comment: Yes, there is only one material applied. http://prntscr.com/v8skmt

Comment: So... "display as" in the viewport display part of object properties? (last guess... if not that please consider uploading the blend file with texture included, I think)

Comment: I forgot to add, every single other material shows up correctly, it's the images that refuse to. Here is the blend file. https://pasteall.org/blend/9593771d44e94b33a2846baedd46298f

Comment: The texture is not packed, here is what I have:https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF4wZ.jpg. Though that indicates that it should render an image... To pack textures in "File>External data>Pack all"

Comment: So, how can i fix it? Try to find another image?

Comment: Well, not necessarily. If was the case, you should render "pink" too. Have you packed the texture in the file you provided?

Comment: I don't know how to pack the texture too, I just saved as a .blend file.

Comment: In File menu, External Data, Pack all. Then save the blend file again.

Comment: Alright. I will upload it now.

Comment: My .blend files won't upload for some reason, it's below the 24mb limit. One thing I forgot to add, the no-texture shows up as black instead of pink. http://prntscr.com/v8tbg2

Comment: I will wait for the blend to upload then send it here,

Comment: For the picture just above, either this is sky (world nodes) or may be a UV map issue?

Comment: Here is the .blend. https://pasteall.org/blend/1db28d703caa4ff8a69f28e1e27a891f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of the file, I don't think your UV unwrap was successful. When I examine the UV map, this is what I see.

[image: UV1]

Just to test, I did a simple Sphere Projection unwrap and it looked more proper.

[image: UV2]

The texture you included didn't work, but I used one of my own, and it seems to be fine now.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The object has no UV map: Blender does not know how to map the texture.

You can either add a *"texture coordinates"* and change the *"image texture"* to *"box"* and tune the *"blend"* value:

[image]

Or create a UV map.